# JDBC Oracle in OSGI concierge

Tags: oracle, osgi-bundle, ojdbc

I need some clue how to use ojdbc8 (I tried with ojdbc6,ojdbc7 never worked also) deployed as OSGi Bundle, I could load the class using Class.load(), however I get the following error when running:

```
java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: bundle
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:421)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:310)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:333)
    at org.eclipse.concierge.BundleImpl$Revision.createURL(BundleImpl.java:2460)
    at org.eclipse.concierge.BundleImpl$JarBundleRevision.findFile(BundleImpl.java:3633)
    at org.eclipse.concierge.BundleImpl$JarBundleRevision.lookupFile(BundleImpl.java:3587)
    at org.eclipse.concierge.BundleImpl$Revision$BundleClassLoader.findOwnResources(BundleImpl.java:3220)
    at org.eclipse.concierge.BundleImpl$Revision$BundleClassLoader.findResource1(BundleImpl.java:2747)
    at org.eclipse.concierge.BundleImpl$Revision$BundleClassLoader.findResource0(BundleImpl.java:2685)
    at org.eclipse.concierge.BundleImpl$Revision$BundleClassLoader.findResource(BundleImpl.java:2541)
    at org.eclipse.concierge.BundleImpl$Revision$BundleClassLoader.getResource(BundleImpl.java:2517)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream(ClassLoader.java:1307)
    at java.lang.Class.getResourceAsStream(Class.java:2223)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.SQLStateMapping.doGetMappings(SQLStateMapping.java:208)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.SQLStateMapping.getMappings(SQLStateMapping.java:194)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.<clinit>(DatabaseError.java:1075)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDiagnosabilityMBean.getDescription(OracleDiagnosabilityMBean.java:96)
    at javax.management.StandardMBean.getMBeanInfo(StandardMBean.java:456)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.getNewMBeanClassName(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:333)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerMBean(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:319)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.registerMBean(JmxMBeanServer.java:522)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.registerMBeans(OracleDriver.java:409)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver$1.run(OracleDriver.java:241)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.<clinit>(OracleDriver.java:237)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.isDriverAllowed(DriverManager.java:556)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:661)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
    at nz.co.spark.cg.shared.sql.SQLUtils.getDBConnection(SQLUtils.java:19)
    at nz.co.spark.cg.shared.sql.SQLUtils.createLocalDB(SQLUtils.java:29)
    at nz.co.spark.cg.extractor.task.ChatExtractorJob.<init>(ChatExtractorJob.java:61)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleJobFactory.newJob(SimpleJobFactory.java:56)
    at org.quartz.simpl.PropertySettingJobFactory.newJob(PropertySettingJobFactory.java:69)
    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.initialize(JobRunShell.java:127)
    at org.quartz.core.QuartzSchedulerThread.run(QuartzSchedulerThread.java:375)
java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: bundle
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:421)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:310)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:333)
    at org.eclipse.concierge.BundleImpl$Revision.createURL(BundleImpl.java:2460)
    at org.eclipse.concierge.BundleImpl$JarBundleRevision.findFile(BundleImpl.java:3633)
    at org.eclipse.concierge.BundleImpl$JarBundleRevision.lookupFile(BundleImpl.java:3587)
    at org.eclipse.concierge.BundleImpl$Revision$BundleClassLoader.findOwnResources(BundleImpl.java:3220)
    at org.eclipse.concierge.BundleImpl$Revision$BundleClassLoader.findResource1(BundleImpl.java:2747)
    at org.eclipse.concierge.BundleImpl$Revision$BundleClassLoader.findResource0(BundleImpl.java:2685)
    at org.eclipse.concierge.BundleImpl$Revision$BundleClassLoader.findResource(BundleImpl.java:2541)
    at org.eclipse.concierge.BundleImpl$Revision$BundleClassLoader.getResource(BundleImpl.java:2517)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream(ClassLoader.java:1307)
    at java.util.ResourceBundle$Control$1.run(ResourceBundle.java:2686)
    at java.util.ResourceBundle$Control$1.run(ResourceBundle.java:2671)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.util.ResourceBundle$Control.newBundle(ResourceBundle.java:2670)
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.loadBundle(ResourceBundle.java:1510)
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.findBundle(ResourceBundle.java:1474)
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.findBundle(ResourceBundle.java:1428)
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.findBundle(ResourceBundle.java:1428)
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl(ResourceBundle.java:1370)
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle(ResourceBundle.java:782)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.Message11.msg(Message11.java:36)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.findMessage(DatabaseError.java:939)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDiagnosabilityMBean.getDescription(OracleDiagnosabilityMBean.java:96)
    at javax.management.StandardMBean.getMBeanInfo(StandardMBean.java:456)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.getNewMBeanClassName(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:333)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerMBean(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:319)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.registerMBean(JmxMBeanServer.java:522)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.registerMBeans(OracleDriver.java:409)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver$1.run(OracleDriver.java:241)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.<clinit>(OracleDriver.java:237)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.isDriverAllowed(DriverManager.java:556)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:661)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
    at nz.co.spark.cg.shared.sql.SQLUtils.getDBConnection(SQLUtils.java:19)
    at nz.co.spark.cg.shared.sql.SQLUtils.createLocalDB(SQLUtils.java:29)
    at nz.co.spark.cg.extractor.task.ChatExtractorJob.<init>(ChatExtractorJob.java:61)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleJobFactory.newJob(SimpleJobFactory.java:56)
    at org.quartz.simpl.PropertySettingJobFactory.newJob(PropertySettingJobFactory.java:69)
    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.initialize(JobRunShell.java:127)
    at org.quartz.core.QuartzSchedulerThread.run(QuartzSchedulerThread.java:375)
java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: bundle
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:421)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:310)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:333)
    at org.eclipse.concierge.BundleImpl$Revision.createURL(BundleImpl.java:2460)
    at org.eclipse.concierge.BundleImpl$JarBundleRevision.findFile(BundleImpl.java:3633)
    at org.eclipse.concierge.BundleImpl$JarBundleRevision.lookupFile(BundleImpl.java:3587)
    at org.eclipse.concierge.BundleImpl$Revision$BundleClassLoader.findOwnResources(BundleImpl.java:3220)
    at org.eclipse.concierge.BundleImpl$Revision$BundleClassLoader.findResource1(BundleImpl.java:2747)
    at org.eclipse.concierge.BundleImpl$Revision$BundleClassLoader.findResource0(BundleImpl.java:2685)
    at org.eclipse.concierge.BundleImpl$Revision$BundleClassLoader.findResource(BundleImpl.java:2541)
    at org.eclipse.concierge.BundleImpl$Revision$BundleClassLoader.getResource(BundleImpl.java:2517)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream(ClassLoader.java:1307)
    at java.lang.Class.getResourceAsStream(Class.java:2223)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.<clinit>(OracleDriver.java:323)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.isDriverAllowed(DriverManager.java:556)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:661)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
    at nz.co.spark.cg.shared.sql.SQLUtils.getDBConnection(SQLUtils.java:19)
    at nz.co.spark.cg.shared.sql.SQLUtils.createLocalDB(SQLUtils.java:29)
    at nz.co.spark.cg.extractor.task.ChatExtractorJob.<init>(ChatExtractorJob.java:61)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleJobFactory.newJob(SimpleJobFactory.java:56)
    at org.quartz.simpl.PropertySettingJobFactory.newJob(PropertySettingJobFactory.java:69)
    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.initialize(JobRunShell.java:127)
    at org.quartz.core.QuartzSchedulerThread.run(QuartzSchedulerThread.java:375)
```

That is happening inside oracle jdbc driver, in the class SQLStateMapping, the classr is trying to get a Resource file, using SQLStateMapping.class.getResourceAsStream("error..xml");

That happens because inside the OSGi bundle it changes the URL inserting "bundle" word on it, and the resource never returns correctly throwing java.net.MalformedURLException. Does any one know how to solve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would like to use JDBC in OSGi I recommend you the usage of ([PAX-JDBC](https://github.com/ops4j/org.ops4j.pax.jdbc)). It makes all required glue which will register DataSourceFactory from JDBC drivers, and if you are using ConfigAdmin service you can register DataSource-s too. When I use a library which able to handle JDBC connection or DataSource I get the instance from OSGi services and using that. The benefits of it you can use connection poolers too, PAX-JDBC supports it out of box. If the documentation not clear I can extend this answer with some example, but for start there is a good [tutorial](http://liquid-reality.de/Karaf-Tutorial/06/). It is based on karaf, but it can be adapted in any standard OSGi implementation.